# Why out-of-bounds occurs with memchr() on mac os

Tags: c, macos, overflow

I encounter a problem of overflow when use memchr() on mac os x.

Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *content="http\r\nUser";
    int content_size = strlen(content);
    char *contmem = malloc(content_size+1);
    memset(contmem, '\0', content_size+1);
    memcpy(contmem, content, content_size);
    printf("%c\n", *(content+content_size));
    printf("%c\n", *(contmem+content_size));
    char *t = memchr(content, 't', content_size);
    printf("%c\n", *t);
    return 0;
}
```

It works normally on linux, i.e., my fedora 16, and prints the correct value of t.
But when I run the same piece of code on Mac, Segmentation Fault occurs!!

After debugging with gdb, I take the saying:

```
(gdb) print t
$7 = 0xf4b <Address 0xf4b out of bounds>
```

Then I try to rewrite the memchr function in this test file:

```
static char*
memchr(const char *data, int c, unsigned long len){
    char *tp = data;
    unsigned long i;
    for( i = 0; i<len; i++){
        if((int)*tp == c){
            return tp;
        }else{
            tp = tp+1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the output seems correct!

```
 (gdb) print t
 $1 = 0x100000f1d "ttp\r\nUser"
```

So I am confused with the abnormal behavior of memchr() on mac os, while other mem functions like memset() memcpy() works fine.

How can I run the test without rewriting the memchr() on mac??

Thanks.

Comment: Your replacement has Undefined Behavior (i.e., there's no `return` if it reaches the end of the buffer without finding the target byte).

Comment: this code is working fine on my mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`memchr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr) is declared in `string.h`, for which there is no include directive in the posted code. This means an implicit function declaration will be generated by compiler (which should emit a warning) which returns an `int`. If the `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(char*)` are different on your system this may explain the problem. Add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: Yeah, this including has eliminate the overflow error!! Thanks. But the implicit operation of memchr() still confuses me, and what is the difference between the built-in version and glibc version??

Answer (score 1):

Your code should indeed work. Your compiler may be using built-in versions of the mem***() functions. Try to include string.h to force the use of the libc versions.